# Contracts - static analysis incorrectly flagging Ensure condition

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, code-contracts

I've spent a few hours on this issue... here's my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(this Func<T> generator) where T : class
{
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll<T>(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>(), item => item != null));

  if (generator == null)
    yield break;

  T t;
  while ((t = generator()) != null)
    yield return t;
}


public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this TextReader reader)
{
  Contract.Requires(reader != null);
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<string>>() != null);
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll<string>(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<string>>(), s => s != null));

  return Generate(() => reader.ReadLine());
}
```

For some reason, the last line (the invocation of Generate()) is being flagged as "`ensures unproven: Contract.ForAll<string>(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<string>>(), s => s != null)`". I don't see how that can be the case - Generate guarantees that it won't return null items, and the analyzer doesn't complain about it. What am I doing wrong?

[Edit] Hmm... all of a sudden I am getting a warning on the Generate function - same thing, the ensure is unproven. I could swear this wasn't happening before, but in any case - now the problem has moved. How can I persuade the analyzer that there's no way to return null items? Or, alternatively, where am I wrong and the function *can* return null items?

[Edit] Blech... [this article](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2010/06/26/net-4-code-contracts-and-iterators/) says "post conditions (i.e. Contract.Ensure) are not supported by static checker" (in iterators)... can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Nitpick: people in the field use the word "correct" for the ability of the analyzer never to diagnose as true a property that isn't. I momentarily thought this question was very interesting. In the context of a true property diagnosed as unproven, I would recommend to use "imprecisely" instead.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that false negatives are as incorrect as false positives :) In both cases, I can't do my job because of it.

Answer (score 1):

`yield return` won't currently work with `Contract.Ensures` due to interactions between the compiler and ccrewrite.

Best you can do at the moment is to write a private method without contracts and then `Assume` the required contracts in a public method:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> RealGenerate<T>(this Func<T> generator) where T : class
{

  if (generator == null)
    yield break;

  T t;
  while ((t = generator()) != null)
    yield return t;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(this Func<T> generator) where T: class
{
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>(), item => item != null));

  var result = RealGenerate(generator);
  Contract.Assume(result != null);
  Contract.Assume(Contract.ForAll(result, item => item != null));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I must be doing something wrong, it's still not working. The line with "return result" has the squiggles with the legend "... ensures unproven...".

Comment: Sorry, didn't actually test the code because I didn't have time - but I'd used that pattern before. The container analysis (i.e. `ForAll` and `Exists`) is also still "in development" so this might be a case that it doesn't work with at the moment. Actually, if you change `IEnumerable<T>` to `T[]` or `List<T>` this works... I'm beginning to think this is something to do with the lazy nature of `IEnumerable<T>` or something like the fact that some enumerables can only be enumerated once.... might be worth asking this on the Code Contracts forums.

Comment: Yes... I needed it to be lazy, for multiple reasons (like I'm reading from a text file, and I don't want the whole file in memory - I want to process each line separately)